# What is really this limit?

Tags: limits

I recently find a limit that shows $\pi$:

$$\lim_{n\to \infty }\, 2^{n} \underbrace{\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\cdots +\sqrt{2}}}}}_n= \pi$$

The problem is that I cannot know what the limit says I talk about positive and negatives.With what order are they?

Comment: I copied the limit that I think you're referring to.  Did I get it right?  If so, I am still having trouble understanding your question.

Comment: What does "I cannot know what the limit says I talk about positive and negatives" mean?

Comment: The question, as I understand it, when is there minus within the radicals and when is there plus?

Comment: @Matthew Leingang Yes you are right.

Comment: They're all positive except the second...